# Ubuntu Software Center hangs when installing software while other software is queued 

Tags: software-center

When installing software via Software Center I have no problems if there is no queue. If anything is queued up, however, any installing software hangs at applying changes. Any thoughts on this? I recently upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10 and had no problems before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling Software Center solved this issue.